# Issue with JSON

Tags: php, json

I am trying to have PHP read an XML file and then convert it to JSON to use in some classes that I wrote. The problem I am having is it will not loop thru all XML nodes.

For some reason it will only return one node and not both. My guess is maybe my JSON object is not formatted correctly. I have been messing with this for about 2 days, ugh! I am new to this so go easy on me ;)

#### tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tracker>
    <student>
        <id>0425655</id>
        <lname>Doe</lname>
        <fname>John</fname>
    </student>
    <student>
        <id>0123456</id>
        <lname>Smith</lname>
        <fname>Jane</fname>
    </student>
</tracker>
```

#### xml.php

```
class xml
{
    private $path;
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path; 
    }
    public function xmlParse()
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($this->path);
        return json_encode($xml->children());
    }
}
```

#### json.php

```
class json
{
    private $xmlArray;
    public function __construct($xmlArray)
    {
        $this->xmlArray = $xmlArray;
    }
    public function getJSON()
    {
        $json = json_decode($this->xmlArray);
        foreach($json->student as $v)
        {
            return 'ID: '.$v->id.'Last: '.$v->lname.'First: '.$v->fname;
        } 
    }
}
```

I know I can pass `true` as a second parameter to `json_decode()`, but I wanted to work with objects.

Here's the output for the `json_decode()` (after passing it through getJSON for formatting):

```
{
    "student": [
        {
            "id": "0425655",
            "lname": "Doe",
            "fname": "John"
        },
        {
            "id": "0123456",
            "lname": "Smith",
            "fname": "Jane"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your class is poorly-named. So is your question title.

Comment: What's wrong with the JSON output? It looks fine to me. You should explain what output you're _looking for_, and how it differs from what you're _getting_.

Comment: +1 For posting the code (albeit only snippets, instead of like 5 consecutive lines. However, you forgot to tell us the exact problem ;) . What output are you getting in what step, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Both student nodes are in that JSON output, they're in an array in the `student` key of the object.

Comment: Sorry I will try to clearify things up. What I am trying to do is create a web app for my work that will allow someone to upload and xml file with students. Keep in mind the xml file information will be changing. Administration uses Microsoft Excel for data entry and then outputs it as an xml file. With this xml file I want a php page that will show a list of students based on what information is in the xml file.

Comment: @Tomalak - keep in mind these are generic class names for this example. The result I am getting only outputs the first xml node information, I top return ALL nodes.

Comment: @user738910: We know what you're doing. Excel is not relevant and just muddies the issue. Your question was OK as it was. You should read the answers, which explain the problem.

Comment: @user738910: The JSON you posted contains information on both nodes. Read it again. (What does "I top return" mean?)

Comment: @phihag - the json_encode() seems to be working properly, but it's the getJSON() that I seem to have something screwed up.

Comment: @user738910 Read my answer: You used `return` instead of `echo` in `getJSON`.

Comment: ??? lol, if your gonna be an a$$ don't waste my time Tomalak. I was trying to provide the information you requested.

Comment: @user738910: Please provide an example of what you expect the JSON output to be structured.

Comment: @user738910 Please keep your manners on stackoverflow. Tomalak was just trying to help and pointing out that it's way easier to solve a problem with a couple of lines of code and input instead than one with a whole mess of different programs, inputs and platforms. Please try to reduce code and input size in further answers. For information about how to ask questions, read http://sscce.org/

Comment: @phihag - I am not really sure what you are getting at. To create an output using return simply print($ob->getJSON()) and this is why I use return. Is this not a good way of doing this?

Comment: @user738910 This discussion belongs in my answer, not the question. `return` immediately exits the `getJSON` function, including the `foreach` statement. Aggregate the result and then return it after, not in, the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I am trying to think of a better way of getting across my problem and I am failing. I guess what I am having problems with is in the json class the foreach() is not returning all the xml nodes. When I instantiate the class using print($obj->getJSON()) I want it to list all students, but currently it only does one, the first student in the xml. Hope this helps and forgive me being an ass, just felt like I was being attacked a little bit.

Comment: @phihag - I understand what are you saying now. I did not realize it was ending the loop after the first pass thru. I understand what you are saying now. Thank you :)

Comment: @phihag - Just made the changes and it worked! Great job and thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` immediately, well, *returns* from the current function. You want `echo` for debugging, as in

```
foreach($json->student as $v)
{
    echo 'ID: '.$v->id.'Last: '.$v->lname.'First: '.$v->fname;
}
```

If you want to return the result, either just return the JSON object or parse it into an array or string.

Comment: Thanks, I now see what was going on. I only was looking at the comments under my post and failed to look further down this page to see all of what you guys have wrote. I owe all you an appology for getting frustrated. Sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That JSON string looks right to me, problem lies with the `return` statement - as you're looping through an array, use `echo` instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding your JSON

I reformatted your output. As you can see, there *are* two nodes under "student". Perhaps you missed the `[` and `]` characters.

Format your JSON next time to get a better idea of what's going on. :)

---

### Regarding your function

You also might have missed it because your debug output is broken:

```
foreach($json->student as $v)
{
   return 'ID: '.$v->id.'Last: '.$v->lname.'First: '.$v->fname;
}
```

You return after the first iteration.

Try:

```
$output = '';
foreach ($json->student as $v) {
   $output .= "ID: {$v->id} Last: {$v->lname} First: {$v->fname}\n";
} 
return $output;
```

To be honest, though, I'd expect a function named `getJSON()` to return, well... JSON. Not some author-written string. Your classes and functions are poorly named overall.

Perhaps your function should look like this:

```
public function getJSON()
{
    $json = json_decode($this->xmlArray);

    // some debug output for development
    foreach ($json->student as $v) {
        echo "ID: {$v->id} Last: {$v->lname} First: {$v->fname}\n";
    }

    return $json;
}
```